# divide json on 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, json

i try to divide json array:

```
 var json = [{"date":"23","count":"100"},{"date":"23","count":"100"}]
 var labels = [],data=[];
 for(var i in json){
      labels.push(json[i].date);
      data.push(json[i].count);
  }
  alert(labels);
```

but in alert is only `,` 
What is problem ?
there is https://jsfiddle.net/90597hzy/

Comment: None of the objects in your original `json` array have properties named "date" or "count".

Comment: Change it as this, `labels.push(json[i].label);data.push(json[i].name);`.

Comment: sorry, i forget to change the sample data before post. there ist realy date and count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json does not have `date` & `count` key

Replaced with name & label. It is working as expected

```
var json = [{"name":"23","label":"100"},
               {"name":"23","label":"100"}]
             var labels = [],data=[];
             for(var i in json){
                  labels.push(json[i].name);
                  data.push(json[i].label);
              }
              console.log(labels);
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/90597hzy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [{"name":"23","label":"100"},{"name":"23","label":"100"}]
var labels = [],data=[];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  labels.push(array[i].label);
  data.push(array[i].name);
}

console.log(labels);
console.log(data);
```